# What the right time for registering listener for Share/Search charms

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I need to register different share charm listener for every page. I have 2 pages. I added following code in every one:

```
        DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += App_DataRequested;
```

I added it in constructor of one page and in UserControl_Loaded event of another (first page just doesn't have UserControl_Loaded so why I added it directly to constructor). At the moment when second page tryting to load, I got exception:

```
WinRT information: An event handler has already been registered
Additional information: A method was called at an unexpected time.
```

Where should I place it and what is "right" time to do this??
Also it looks confusing that we have different DataTransferManager for every view, but only one is active at current time. Ever more, I noticed, if you add only one listener for first page, other pages will share this listener anyway. If I have only one shared listener for all pages, is it correct register it in app.xaml.cs?

Comment: yes, app.xaml.cs is what I've done for several apps.

Answer (score 2):

The way I resolved this issue was to deregister the event in the onNavigatedfrom event as below:

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
     {
          DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested -= App_DataRequested;
          base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

Answer (score 1):

In BasePage.cs in constructor I added

```
public BasePage()
{        
    if (!_isListenToDataRequested)
    {
        _isListenToDataRequested = true;

        DataTransferManager manager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();  
        manager.DataRequested += AppDataRequested;
    }
}

private async void AppDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    IShareable shareable = Frame.Content as IShareable;
    if (shareable != null)
    {
        DataRequestDeferral deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => shareable.AppDataRequested(sender, args));

        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

And all my pages look like

```
public sealed partial class ContentPage : IShareable
{
    public void AppDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
    {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution was run this as below**

```
private DataTransferManager dataTransferManager;
```

**Put this in page loaded event**

```
 this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(() =>
            {
                this.dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
                this.dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.OnDataRequested);
            }));
```

**And**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Unregister the current page as a share source.
        this.dataTransferManager.DataRequested -=
            new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>
                (this.OnDataRequested);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing it in the navigating events, the OnNavigatingFrom event will be triggered before the OnNavigatingTo of the page you're going to so you won't have this problem.

```
protected override Task OnNavigatingTo(WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AlternativeNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += dataTransfer_DataRequested;
    return base.OnNavigatingTo(e);
}

protected override Task OnNavigatingFrom(WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AlternativeNavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested -= dataTransfer_DataRequested;
    return base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
}

//Note: This is the WinRT Xaml Toolkit version of the events, but the standard events will work the same way.
```